# How to shorten the editor when the author is same as the editor?

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

In my bibliography, I have a case where the author of an `@Inbook` entry is the same as the editor of the book:

```
@Book{ducktales, Booktitle={Ducktales}, Editor = {Donald Duck}, Year = {2001}}

@Inbook{intro, Title={Introduction}, Crossref = {ducktales}, Author = {Donald Duck}, Pages = {1-10}}
```

The bibliography entry appears like this:

> Donald Duck: Introduction. In: Ducktales (2001), Published by Donald Duck.

However, if the author is the same as the editor, I'd like to have the editor replaced by author. So the entry should look like this:

> Donald Duck: Introduction. In: Ducktales (2001), Published by author.

How can I do that?

Comment: Which bibliography style do you use at present?

Comment: I'm using `authoryear-ibid` with `biblatex`.

Comment: Thanks. I've taken the liberty of deleting the "bibtex" tag and adding a "biblatex" tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can redefine the `byeditor` macros to print `\bibstring[\mkibid]{idem\thefield{gender}}` whenever `editor` and `author` are the same

```
\renewbibmacro*{byeditor}{%
  \ifnameundef{editor}
    {}
    {\usebibmacro{bytypestrg}{editor}{editor}%
     \setunit{\addspace}%
     \ifnamesequal{author}{editor}
       {\bibstring[\mkibid]{idem\thefield{gender}}}
       {\printnames[byeditor]{editor}}%
     \newunit}%
  \usebibmacro{byeditorx}}

\renewbibmacro*{byeditor+others}{%
  \ifnameundef{editor}
    {}
    {\usebibmacro{byeditor+othersstrg}%
     \setunit{\addspace}%
     \ifnamesequal{author}{editor}
       {\bibstring[\mkibid]{idem\thefield{gender}}}
       {\printnames[byeditor]{editor}}%
     \clearname{editor}%
     \newunit}%
  \usebibmacro{byeditorx}%
  \usebibmacro{bytranslator+others}}
```

Of course, you can `\bibstring[\mkibid]{idem\thefield{gender}}` by anything you like above (for example: `author`).

You can do the same for `byauthor`

```
\renewbibmacro*{bybookauthor}{%
  \ifnamesequal{author}{bookauthor}
    {\bibstring[\mkibid]{idem\thefield{gender}}}
    {\printnames{bookauthor}}}
```

---

If you prefer the output "author" instead of "idem".

```
\NewBibliographyString{author}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{author = {author}}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{german}{author = {Autor}}
```

and replace every line

```
{\bibstring[\mkibid]{idem\thefield{gender}}}
```

above by

```
{\bibstring{author}}
```

---

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=authoryear-ibid]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\providecommand*{\mkibid}[1]{#1}
\renewbibmacro*{bybookauthor}{%
  \ifnamesequal{author}{bookauthor}
    {\bibstring[\mkibid]{idem\thefield{gender}}}
    {\printnames{bookauthor}}}

\renewbibmacro*{byeditor}{%
  \ifnameundef{editor}
    {}
    {\usebibmacro{bytypestrg}{editor}{editor}%
     \setunit{\addspace}%
     \ifnamesequal{author}{editor}
       {\bibstring[\mkibid]{idem\thefield{gender}}}
       {\printnames[byeditor]{editor}}%
     \newunit}%
  \usebibmacro{byeditorx}}

\renewbibmacro*{byeditor+others}{%
  \ifnameundef{editor}
    {}
    {\usebibmacro{byeditor+othersstrg}%
     \setunit{\addspace}%
     \ifnamesequal{author}{editor}
       {\bibstring[\mkibid]{idem\thefield{gender}}}
       {\printnames[byeditor]{editor}}%
     \clearname{editor}%
     \newunit}%
  \usebibmacro{byeditorx}%
  \usebibmacro{bytranslator+others}}

\begin{document}
  \nocite{kant:kpv,westfahl:space}
  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]